# Accesing the Views in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I implemented 4 views in AppDelegate depends on requirement it will call the view.I called second(example) view then I pushed to the new view again I pushed to the other new view.I want to go back to the second(example) view. I implemented the code like this [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; but it is poping to previous view and again it go back to the second(example) view. Can any one tell me how it goes directly to the second(example) view.
                                     Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead** of using **popToRootViewController** you need to use **popToViewController** like bellow

```
 self.navigationController popToViewController:secondViewObj animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
popViewControllerAnimated:animated]
```

or

```
popToViewController:yourVC animated:animated]
```

Comment: I implemented that one also but the output is same.

Comment: Take a look on navigation controller stack - NSLOG(@"%@", [self.navigationController viewControllers]);

Comment: it's not correct, it should be stack of view controllers are you sure that navigationController is not nil? Show code example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[pushViewController:obj animated:NO]`.....

Though this will not pop your view, but it will push your view to `obj` that is object of FirstView.

This will simply work as you want, may be not technical way...:)